# Returning "KeyError: " in Python when trying to populate a SQlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, api, cron, keyerror

I am currently getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Stephen/Desktop/projects/Option_History/snapshot.py", line 44, in <module>
    data = (current_timestamp, option['underlying'], option['symbol'], option['description'], option['strike'], option['bid'], option['ask'], option['volume'], option['greeks']['delta'], option['greeks']['gamma'], option['greeks']['theta'], option['greeks']['vega'], option['greeks']['rho'], option['greeks']['phi'], option['greeks']['mid_iv'], option['greeks']['smv_vol'])
KeyError: 'greeks'
```

My code is shown below:

```py
import config, requests, pprint, sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

connection = sqlite3.connect('option_history.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

try:
    cursor.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE option_history (
            timestamp text,
            underlying text,
            symbol text,
            description text,
            strike real,
            bid real,
            ask real,
            volume real,
            delta real,
            gamma real,
            theta real,
            vega real,
            rho real,
            phi real,
            mid_iv real,
            smv_vol real
        )
    """)
except:
    pass


response = requests.get(config.OPTION_CHAIN_URL,
    params={'symbol': 'SPY', 'expiration': '2020-12-04', 'greeks': 'true'},
    headers=config.HEADERS
)

json_response = response.json()
options = json_response['options']['option']

current_timestamp = datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0).isoformat()
print(options)

for option in options:
    data = (current_timestamp, option['underlying'], option['symbol'], option['description'], option['strike'], option['bid'], option['ask'], option['volume'], option['greeks']['delta'], option['greeks']['gamma'], option['greeks']['theta'], option['greeks']['vega'], option['greeks']['rho'], option['greeks']['phi'], option['greeks']['mid_iv'], option['greeks']['smv_vol'])
    
    print(",".join(map(str, data)))

    cursor.execute("""
        INSERT INTO option_history (
            timestamp, underlying, symbol, description, strike, bid, ask, volume, delta, gamma, theta, vega, rho, phi, mid_iv, smv_vol
        ) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    """, data)

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

I was running this code for an entire day every 5 minutes using cron and it properly inserted all the data I needed with no errors. Now when attempting to run it again today using crontab, the DB was not populated with any new data.

The interesting part is that even though I am getting the `KeyError` message, the `data` variable is still populated properly because the

```
print(",".join(map(str, data))
```

line is updating properly with a new API call of data and printing to the console without issue.

Comment: One or more of the options in the returned response do not contain the key `greeks`

Comment: You can try except for the key

Comment: @AbrarAhmed would I include the entire 'data' variable in the try: statement?

Comment: @AbrarAhmed this worked out well from what I can see. appears that SQlite database is populating properly now. can you briefly explain why this is the case and what is happening to solve this error?